# How to update the configuration of a vendor symfony bundle during the kernel build process

Tags: php, symfony

#### Summary

Instead of using a simple `.yaml` file for configuring a vendor bundle, I want to *generate* the given configuration by using a custom, simpler configuration schema (defined in a custom `.yaml` file).

#### Context

I'm using:

- Symfony 5.4
- [RabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle) (this question is not dealing specifically about this bundle, it's just an example)

#### Problem

In my project, configuring RabbitMqBundle is quite tedious, particularly consumers and producers which all have the same ~10-line configuration schema. So, as a little challenge I would like to create a symfony extension with its own configuration key (something like `simple_rabbitmq`), which would allow to give short rules (accordingly to my project) in order to generate the final configuration of RabbitMqBundle.

For example, my actual RabbitMqBundle config looks like this:

```yaml
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            host: '%env(RABBITMQ_HOST)%'
            port: '%env(int:RABBITMQ_PORT)%'
            user: '%env(RABBITMQ_USER)%'
            password: '%env(RABBITMQ_PASSWORD)%'
            vhost: '%env(RABBITMQ_VHOST)%'
            lazy: true
            connection_timeout: 10
            read_write_timeout: 10

    producers:
        foo:
            connection: default
            exchange_options: { name: amq.direct, type: direct }
            default_routing_key: foo
            auto_setup_fabric: true
            queue_options:
                name: foo
                routing_keys: [foo]

        bar:
            connection: default
            exchange_options: { name: amq.direct, type: direct }
            default_routing_key: bar
            auto_setup_fabric: true
            queue_options:
                name: bar
                routing_keys: [bar]

        # ...

    consumers:
        foo:
            connection: default
            exchange_options: { name: amq.direct, type: direct }
            auto_setup_fabric: true
            queue_options:
                name: foo
                routing_keys: [foo]
            enable_logger: true
            callback: App\Amqp\Consumer\FooConsumer

        bar:
            connection: default
            exchange_options: { name: amq.direct, type: direct }
            auto_setup_fabric: true
            queue_options:
                name: bar
                routing_keys: [bar]
            enable_logger: true
            callback: App\Amqp\Consumer\BarConsumer

        # ...
```

But actually in the context of my project, this configuration could be reduced to something like that:

```yaml
simple_rabbitmq:
    default_connection:
        host: '%env(RABBITMQ_HOST)%'
        port: '%env(int:RABBITMQ_PORT)%'
        user: '%env(RABBITMQ_USER)%'
        password: '%env(RABBITMQ_PASSWORD)%'
        vhost: '%env(RABBITMQ_VHOST)%'
        connection_timeout: 10
        read_write_timeout: 10

    producer_consumer_defaults:
        exchange_options: { name: amq.direct, type: direct }

    consumer_namespace: App\Amqp\Consumer

    queues:
        foo: ~
        bar: ~
```

By using this simple configuration, I could build the whole `old_sound_rabbit_mq` configuration tree.

#### Question

I already wrote a symfony extension which handles my custom `simple_rabbitmq` root key (registered in `Kernel::build()`).

But how can I use it in order to update the root config key `old_sound_rabbit_mq`, before it is processed by RabbitMqBundle?

Comment: Have you looked at the [bundle prepending](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html) stuff?  To be honest the description has always confused me and I have never had a use case which made me dig into the details.  But it sort of sounds like it might help?  Assuming that is vague enough.

Comment: @Cerad I found a solution to my problem today, and indeed it deals with `$containerBuilder->prependExtensionConfig` (I will post it when possible)